# What is the best way to install .NET 3.5 on all machines on the network?

Tags: automated-install, .net-3.5

I am a developer and I would like to upgrade a client's application to .NET 3.5. This means .NET 3.5 needs to be installed on every computer on the network that is going to use this application.

The users on this network have restricted permissions and have no ability to install anything. Also, the machines are diverse - desktops, laptops, windows server 2000, server 2003, XP, and Windows 7.

They are worried that because of the diverse computer setups on the network etc, that this is going to be a lot of legwork for them, troubleshooting problems and possibly manually installing on some of these computers.

What is the best way to get .NET 3.5 installed on everyones computers with the least amount of trouble for the administrators?

Comment: You might want to upgrade to 4.0 if you have to do a deploy a new version as 4.0 has a client profile install that is much smaller.

Answer (score 5):

WSUS. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157

Answer (score 4):

You certainly could use Group Policy to deploy the framework. This (older) article details two methods for deploying the framework, the second method being deployment via GPO.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160717.aspx

Comment: I'd go with gpos as well, there is nothing wrong with wsus but GPOs are almost always a known quantity

Answer (score -1):

> What is the best way to get .NET 3.5
>   installed on everones computers with
>   the least amount of trouble for the
>   administrators?

Have them start managing their network. Whow. SOunds like another comapny too cheap to buy ito SCCM or another tool to manage computer configurations ;)

Comment: SCCM (and most of these tools) are really a pain to configure for the small to medium size desktop numbers.  It isn't until you get to medium to large size desktop deployment numbers that SCCM tends to take hold.

Comment: And, installingby hand or with WSUS is a non issue for small businesses either. As the poster is afraid of that, the logical conclusin is that your ocmment is ingnorant and his customer has more than a dozen computers or two.

Comment: no my comment was simply meant that cost usuallly isn't an issue it's usually time and amount of work required to implement that is the problem. I agree that they should be managing their network, and as i commented in this case I'd use a GPO, but there is certainly nothing wrong with suggesting SCCM or another management tool